# Value Loading from a drop down into other textbox

Tags: testing, gwt, selenium, selenium-rc

I uses the selenium for GWT UI testing. It is working properly.
But it is unable to load the drop down in textbox.
for example : When I search "test" in box , it provide me a drop down with a list of value having "test" (test 123 right). Now these value will load in to other boxes which are disabled.

I think selenium is not trigger keydown event . How can it be possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some of your current code so we can see how you're trying to do this?

Comment: selenium.type("css=input.GDPNTKNCHI", "testkaarya@gmail.com");
selenium.fireEvent("css=input.GDPNTKNCHI", "blur");

Answer (score 0):

you can use suggestbox instead of textbox. http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~SuggestBox

Comment: Ashok , I am not allowed to change UI .

Answer (score 0):

You can try `selenium.select("css=input.GDPNTKNCHI", "value=REQUIRED VALUE")` which should select it from the drop down.

Comment: Here's the javadoc for the select method, try it out with (id= optionid) http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#select(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: selenium.keyPress() did my job .